# prevent sqldeveloper from expanding asterisc wildcard in view

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two views, the second one depends on the data from the first and adds some columns from a different table.

In sql developer I define the views as follows:

```
view1:     

select col11, col12, col13, col14, col15, col15, col16, col17 
from table1

view2:
select  view1.*, col22, col23
from view1 join table2 on view1.col11 = table2.col21
```

But when after saving, sqldeveloper expands the "view1.*" part of the second view to the explicit list of columns, so view2 ends up being rewritten as:

```
select  view1.col11, view1.col12, view1.col13, view1.col14, view1.col15, view1.col15, view1.col16, view1.col17, col22, col23
from view1 join table2 on view1.col11 = table2.col21
```

which is harder to read and to mantain.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not SQL Developer doing *that*, it's the database.

You can create the view using the * syntax, but the database will always translate that to a fully qualified SELECT list.

```
CREATE VIEW LOCS
AS select * from locations;
```

Now ask the DB for the DDL, and you get

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "HR"."LOCS" (
    "LOCATION_ID",
    "STREET_ADDRESS",
    "POSTAL_CODE",
    "CITY",
    "STATE_PROVINCE",
    "COUNTRY_ID"
) AS
    SELECT
        "LOCATION_ID",
        "STREET_ADDRESS",
        "POSTAL_CODE",
        "CITY",
        "STATE_PROVINCE",
        "COUNTRY_ID"
    FROM
        locations;
```

The view is defined at run-time, it'll take the existing column list and assume you want the same column names in your view as you want in the underlying objects where those columns are being pulled from.

From the [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#ADMIN11774) -

> Expansion of Defining Queries at View Creation Time When a view is
>   created, Oracle Database expands any wildcard (*) in a top-level view
>   query into a column list. The resulting query is stored in the data
>   dictionary; any subqueries are left intact. The column names in an
>   expanded column list are enclosed in quote marks to account for the
>   possibility that the columns of the base object were originally
>   entered with quotes and require them for the query to be syntactically
>   correct.

Comment: so, there's no way to tell the db to stop translating the wildcard?

Comment: @PrefijoSustantivo correct - but, if you want to keep your code in a source control system,  you can always save your original DDL there and recall it later - just note that * can change. Columns get renamed, dropped, and added.